# Simple question for the Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $a$ and $b$ be algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}~(a,b\neq0)$.
>
> Now, suppose that $K=\mathbb{Q}(a+bi)$ be a Galois extension over $\mathbb{Q}$, and that $\mathbb{Q}(a^{2}+b^{2})\subseteq K$.
>
> Show that the order of the Galois group $G:=\textrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ is even.

In this problem, I have the following two questions:

Q1) Since $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$, is it true that there is an element $\sigma\in G$ so that $\sigma(a+bi)=a-bi$?

Q2) If the question 1 is true, why do we need the condition `$\mathbb{Q}(a^{2}+b^{2})\subseteq K$' ?

Give some advice and comment. Thank you!

Comment: About Q1: That element of the Galois group has order 2, so if it exists, you're done right there by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: You are right. The fact that $K$ is Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$ already implies that $a^2+b^2\in K$.

Comment: Indeed, as Jyrki notes, the hypothesis that $a^{2}+b^{2} \in K$ is superfluous. Let $\tau \colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ denote complex conjugation, and let $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a+bi$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\tau$ fixes the coefficients of $f$, it follows that $\tau(a+bi) = a-bi$ is also a root of $f$. Since $K$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$ (hence normal) and has a contains a root of $f$ (namely $a+bi$), it follows that $f$ splits over $K$, and so $a-bi$ is also in $K$.

Comment: In other words if $L/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois of odd degree then $L$ is totally real (all its embeddings to $\Bbb{C}$ are contained in $\Bbb{R}$). With $\sigma$ a non-real embedding and $\rho$ the complex conjugaison then $\sigma^{-1}\rho \sigma$ is an automorphism of order $2$ so $[L:L^{\sigma^{-1}\rho \sigma}]=2$ (equivalently grouping $g$ with $ g \sigma^{-1}\rho \sigma$ gives $|G|/2$ pairs).